# Why does UI not load after setContentView(), but only after onCreate() executes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-asynctask

In my onCreate method, I setContentView() at the very start

```
inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
//    root.setBackgroundColor(color50);
    setContentView(root);
```

...
Near the end of onCreate() I call a custom asynctask and get the results from it. However, my app's screen stay black even only until the task completes executing.

```
try {
        task = (DatabaseTask) new DatabaseTask().execute(new DatabaseTaskParams(activity, images));
        helper = task.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DatabaseTask", "stack trace", e);
    }

    suggestions = helper.getKeywords();
```

Why does this occur? Is it because of my XML, or is it because onCreate only renders the UI after it is called, or something else?

Here's my XML for the root of the activity

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_photos_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:context="dtancompany.gallerytest.MainActivity">
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_add_panel"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="0dp"
        sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <GridView android:id="@+id/grid_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/add_keyword_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="16dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="64"
                android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:src="@drawable/plus"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_below="@id/edit_text"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using Fragment or Activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this occur?

Because you are calling `get()` on your `AsyncTask`. `get()` says "oh, yes, that `AsyncTask` I just executed, nevermind, let's tie up the main application thread waiting for it instead".

Instead of blocking the main application thread waiting for your database I/O to complete, move your update-the-UI logic into `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`.